# How do I find least cost path over a DEM based on slope magnitude and direction?

Tags: dem, algorithm, direction, cost-path

What sort of algorithms can I use to find a least cost path through a DEM where it costs more to traverse a cell going downhill or uphill than it does to follow the contour of the land?

All the examples I've seen involve creating a least cost surface where the *magnitude* of the slope is part of the cost - but the *direction* isn't.

Additionally, the examples assume the cost to travel through a cell does not depend on the direction of travel.

Comment: Have you reviewed the ArcGIS `PathDistance` command for Spatial Analyst?  If you're interested in algorithms rather than just software, it may help to notice this is an example of a [Calculus of variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) problem.  In fact, by introducing a third dimension to represent all possible orientations at each point (the [circle bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_bundle) over the region of interest), this becomes a least-cost problem within a 3D space (which can be gridded into voxels for a raster-based solution).

Comment: +1 even if you are not using ArcGIS (you don't say), the ESRI explanations that whuber points you towards are a great overview from which you can work out how to do it in some other application.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I overlooked the vertical cost component in the PathDistance.  If I run into bugs with the PathDistance it would be nice to have an algorithm for Plan B.  Although the Calculus of variations is a bit over my head.  It mentions "functionals" ... does that imply I could use [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and not have to worry about learning the math?

Comment: LOL!  That's a nice example of a collision of technical terms in GIS.  In mathematics, the term "functional" is usually used for a *function* whose domain itself consists of functions.  (The Riemann integral is a good example: it assigns a number to real-valued functions.)  When you find an optimal corridor for a pipeline, your functional assigns a "score" or "value" to any possible route.  Because a route would be described as a path--that is, assignment of a point in space to the interval of times needed to traverse that route--"functional" is apt.

Comment: @whuber My understanding of functional programming is that it lets you treat functions as if they were data. A spreadsheet, for example, does this. That seems consistent with the math definition. In a way, a raster is like a spreadsheet where all the cells are numbers. It seems like rasters could borrow this idea from spreadsheets and be generalized so that cells could store numbers _or_ functions. The PathDistance is basically assigning the same function across all cells, isn't it?

Comment: You're right that the concepts all relate to the same abstract mathematical definition of "function," but the relationships are very different. Abstractly, PathDistance is obtained by looking at the set of functions from a Real interval into the region covered by the impedance grid. The impedance assigns a Real value to every possible such path, the "objective function." For every point x, PathDistance finds a path for which the objective is smallest and assigns that optimal value to the point x. It thereby assigns a *Real number* to each cell.  When you backtrack to obtain actual *paths,*...

Comment: @whuber  Thanks.  I think I'll stick with PathDistance, and remain functionally illiterate for the time being.

Comment: [cont'd] you have the capability of associating a *path* to each cell.  In that sense, the "backlink" raster is indirectly representing a path-valued function defined on a part of the earth's surface.  Incidentally, when you do all this using "map algebra," you are doing functional programming: your grids represent functions (assignments of Real numbers to points on earth) and you are processing them as indivisible entities.  If you attempt to loop over cells, you are breaking that functional programming paradigm.

Comment: see GRASS GIS. you may be looking for r.drain - grass.fbk.eu/grass62/manuals/html62_user/r.drain.html

also check r.cost and r.walk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArcMap Path Distance tools can do this, although it's moderately complex. Specifically, you need to use [the horizontal and vertical factors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/How_the_horizontal_and_vertical_factors_affect_path_distance/009z000000z9000000/). This looks at the aspect/elevation to figure out whether it's going uphill, downhill, or parallel to the slope, and assigns a different weight to each direction of approach.